# Issue cleaning up heap allocated resources across a Windows DLL module boundary

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

```
/*
```

It is my understanding that a Windows process which loads one or more dynamic link libraries (DLLs) into its address space will share that address space with all the loaded DLLs -- meaning these DLLs can read and write to any memory in the processes address space.  However, when objects are allocated on the heap, each module (whether it be the `.exe` or one of the process' loaded DLLs) allocates from its own heap.  For this reason, it is critical to deallocate memory against the same heap which performed the allocation.

That all makes sense to me and I thought that I might use a `std::unique_ptr` to help keep things organized.  This is the approach that I used. (I don't have my compiler handy at the moment, but I think these snippets/pseudo code will be clear enough to convey my intentions:

```
*/
```

**Library.h**

```
class ILibrary
{
   public:
   virtual void DoStuff() = 0;
};

struct Deleter
{
  void operator()(ILibrary *p)
  {
    delete p;
  }
};

typedef std::unique_ptr<ILibrary, Deleter> Ptr;

//*MyLibrary.dll*
//Includes Library.h
//Exports:

void GetMyLibrary(Ptr & library)
{
    library = Ptr(new MyLibrary);  // point (1)
}

//**Program.exe**
//Includes Library.h
//Imports MyLibrary.dll (GetMyLibrary export)

int main()
{
    Ptr local;
    MyLibrary->GetMyLibrary(local);
    local->DoStuff();
} // heap corruption on cleanup
```

You can see that both my library and main program use the same header Library.h.  I create the variable `local` to hold the pointer to my library.  The GetMyLibrary method (invoked within the DLL) allocates and assigns a `new unique_ptr` to the reference I passed in.  I used assignment at "point 1" because I want the Deleter from the context of the DLL to be used for cleanup, not the Deleter that was originally assigned to the `local` variable in my main program.  Meaning, when local goes out of scope, I want its cleanup to trigger the DLL's Deleter, not the one that was initially assigned to it (i.e. I used `library = Ptr(new MyLibrary)` instead of `library.reset(new MyLibrary)` because I want the Deleter to be invoked from the context of the DLL)

Anyways, the program seems to work except that during cleanup, when the local `unique_ptr` destructs, I get a heap corruption exception (in debug) that leads me to believe I'm deleting off the wrong heap (ie. the `unique_ptr` isn't behaving as I expected)

Ultimately, I ended up solving the issue another way which seems to be much cleaner, but I just was curious why the approach above was failing?

Comment: "**the** heap" - that's a large part of your problem. As far as Windows is concerned, **the** heap is returned by [`GetProcessHeap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366569(v=vs.85).aspx), and that heap _is_ shared between EXE and DLL's (hence the name "process heap").

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll read up on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your deleter is a part of unique_ptr and is invoked from main when the pointer goes out of scope.

You should either provide `GetMyLibrary()`/`FreeMyLibrary()` in DLL and handle memory allocation/deallocation there (using RAII on applications side), or pass an allocator to `GetMyLibrary()` and make memory allocation and deallocation application's responsibility.

Comment: Thanks for your answer...I'm still a bit confused.  I get what you're saying about using Get/Free exports...thats how I've typically done this in the past, but I don't quite understand why my approach above is breaking down.  When I call the GetMyLibrary export, code in the DLL executes to instantiate a unique_ptr and new up an instance of the library. That unique_ptr has a custom Deleter (which resides in the DLL code) to free the corresponding object.  So when I copy the unique_ptr (via ref) from the DLL to the unique_ptr in main, I am expecting the Deleter in the DLL to be invoked

Comment: (Similar to calling the FreeMyLibrary() function you mentioned)  What am I missing?

Comment: Type `Deleter` here is a part of type `Ptr`. `unique_ptr`, I believe, instantiates this object (of type `Deleter`) either on construction or first call to `get_deleter()`, both of which happen in your `main()`. You could pass plain function as deleter, but it wouldn't be the best idea to use `unique_ptr` on dll/app boundary. Imagine if dll was compiled with different compiler or standard library or even a different versions of thereof.

Comment: Ah, I get it now.  For some reason I was thinking the Deleter was merely a functor that was dynamically assigned at runtime (vs. a type within the unique_ptr template)  It all makes sense now.  Thank you for your answer.